# Proof of theorem in infimum and supremum

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum

[image]

The first line is the statement that I want to prove. Let A and B be bounded non-empty subsets of R. Can someone please tell me does my proof (especially second last line) of this question valid or not?

Comment: Looks good to me.  Minor touch-ups: You might want to say "_without loss of generality_ assume $\min[inf(A), inf(B)] = inf(A)$." Also, "let $\forall c \in A \cup B$" could just be "For all $c \in A \cup B$ we have" or "Fix $c \in A \cup B$."  You end up getting $inf(A) \leq c$ for all such $c \in A \cup B$, and I see that this is why your equation (1) holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is ok. Nice job.

Now, hints for improving:

- It is good to point out that you can suppose WLOG that $\min\{\inf A, \inf B\} = \inf A$.
- The part "let $\forall \ c \in A \cup B$" has this unnecessary $\forall$. You can just say "let $c \in A \cup B$" and go on.
- Write more. Don't be afraid to show your ideas explictly.

And since you didn't seem so sure of the second last line, I'll give a proof of what you used.

**Lemma:** Let $X \subseteq Y \subseteq \Bbb R$ be lower bounded sets. Then $\inf Y \leq \inf X$.

**Proof:** Take $x \in X$. Since $X \subseteq Y$, $x \in Y$ and so $\inf Y \leq x$. Then $\inf Y$ is a lower bound for $X$, and by definition of infimum, we obtain $\inf Y \leq \inf X$.